Question about Voltage in circuits
What does for example "9V on a battery measure" really measure, is it the electrical potential of a single Coloumb of charge provided by the battery? Is it the potential difference? If it's the latter then the potential difference of what, electrons as they move? If yes then shouldn't it be negative as electrons lose electrical potential energy as they move and we take the absolute value of charge
I would prefer a more mathematical and straight up answer, that doesn't use analogies, because usually analogies that explain voltage like water falling from high potential to low potential I don't really like, because they have an explanation, there's gravity, and negative charges move from low potential to high potential by definition.

I have looked at your previous questions and I have doubt on your knowledge that you have right now, you can understand any of the answers. Go to this: a source of voltage and two serial resistors. Learn how to compute the voltage, the currant and the energy each resistor gets. Unless you have a basic understanding, no telling about Maxwell equations or electro-weak interactions will benefit you. No offense meant.

Water falling in a gravitational potential is a bit more than an analogy. It is the same thing described by the same mathematics.  Objects with mass want to travel from high to low gravitational potential. Likewise, positive charges travel from high to low electrical potential, known as voltage. It really can't be reduced to simpler terms than that.

The measure of 9V indicates the potential difference between the two post of the battery.
As a result of chemical reactions occurring in the battery, that can be quantitatively understood in terms of chemical potential, a corresponding potential difference giving rise to an electric field exists between the battery terminals. On a physical level, electrons move from the high potential terminal to the low potential terminal, passing through a difference of 9V in the process, i.e. the voltage dropped by the battery.


is it the electrical potential of a single Coloumb of charge provided by the battery? Is it the potential difference? If it's the latter then the potential difference of what, electrons as they move?

When we talk about "potential difference" we're talking about a property of the two points in space being discussed, not of any charge or charged particles.
If there is +1 V of potential difference between points A and B then it means that it takes 1 J of energy to move 1 C of charge from point B to point A, or 2 J of energy to move 2 C of charge. But it doesn't mean the potential is a property of the charge. The potential is a property of the two points as they are located in the system, and it's defined even if there is no free charge at all present to be moved around between the points.
The potential energy in the system depends on how much charge is present and where it is located. The potential at different points in the system does not.

If yes then shouldn't it be negative as electrons lose electrical potential energy as they move and we take the absolute value of charge

When calculating the potential we assume the charge to be moved between the points will be a positive charge.
When calculating the potential energy difference when moving some specific charge between the points we absolutely must consider the sign of the charge and not take the absolute value.

Voltage is a measure for the difference of the electric potential on 2 different places $U = \phi(r_1) - \phi(r_2)$. The gradient of the electric potential is the electric field $-\nabla\phi(r) =  \vec E(r)$. This means the electric field always points in the direction of lowering potential. Now Voltage, electric potential, and electric field are all defined before and independently of acting on a charge. When multiplying the electric field with the charge its acting on, you get a force $F = q \cdot E$. When doing the same with the electric potential your get potential energy $W = q \cdot \phi$. When doing it with the Voltage you get a potential energy difference $\Delta W = q \cdot U$. Using a negative charge here just means the force is acting in opposite direction.
Now coming back to your question the voltage of the battery measures the difference between the
electrical potentials at the 2 poles of your battery and is defined independently of, on  what charge it is acting on.

The electric potential is not the divergence of the electric field. The divergence of the electric field is one of the Maxwell equations:$$\nabla\cdot\vec E(\vec r)=\rho(\vec r)/\epsilon_0,$$ where $\rho(\vec r)$ is the charge distribution.

@AlbertusMagnus You are obviously right. I don’t know what kind of stroke hit me there, but I surely hope it has no lingering effects.

Hahaha.. I have been blaming mine on allergy pills..

If you want a rigorous answer (as long as you don't get one on forums), I recommend consulting a textbook.
I also just have basic knowledge of this so apologies if I make any mistakes.
It might be possible that you're just referring to the electromotive force of a battery, which is dimensionally similar (but defined differently) to voltage.
Suppose you have a circuit that already has current flowing. That is, a battery has set up an electric field along the wire and that has caused a net movement of charge (electrons, in this case). Charge doesn't accumulate anywhere in a circuit so you can assume that whatever amount of electrons exit one side of the battery, the same amount enters the other side. Electrons are supposed to exit the side the lower voltage and enter the side with the higher voltage. So far so good. However, when an electron enters the side with the higher voltage, how is it supposed to go 'through' the battery and exit out of the lower voltage side? An electron doesn't want to go to regions with lower voltage. This is where the battery comes in, it does work (doesn't matter how) on the electron so that it goes from higher to lower potential. Then we define the electromotive force of the battery as the work done per unit charge:
$E_{emf}=\frac{dW}{dq}$

In theory, a battery is a pure and infinite voltage source, giving, for example, 9V whatever you do. In practice, any battery has an output impedance, decreasing your effective voltage depending on how much current you draw. This is particularly annoying if you measure the voltage using an expensive high impedance device, showing you 9V, but if you attach a light bulb it will not shine as the impedance within the over-aged battery gets most of the voltage and thus most of the energy.
Can you do the calculations for a Voltage source and two resistors? (One resistor inside the batteries, and the other outside.)
